# Apply filter sql on map CARTO.js using a Builder vizjson

Tags: carto, carto.js

I have a new account in Carto (using Builder). I have found several examples using SQL filters. But when I apply them to my map, they do not work. Could it be related to the domain change on the API call?

Anyone know how to apply a SQL filter using CARTO.js and CARTO Builder `vizjson` and show his result on a map?

**UPDATE:**

After @ramiroaznar request, I have added my code. A SQL filter could be `SELECT * FROM distritos where coddistrit = '1'`. When I use the sample provided on the answer the map does not work. Again, the problem could be related to the domain of the API call when querying.

- API call that works:

  `http://rodrigorodriguezmartin.carto.com/api/v1/map?stat_tag=API&config={"version"%3A"1.0.0"%2C"stat_tag"%3A"API"%2C"layers"%3A\[{"type"%3A"cartodb"%2C"options"%3A{"sql"%3A"select * from distritos"%2C"cartocss"%3A"%23layer { polygon-fill%3A %23374C70%3B polygon-opacity%3A 0.9%3B polygon-gamma%3A 0.5%3B line-color%3A %23FFF%3B line-width%3A 1%3B line-opacity%3A 0.5%3B line-comp-op%3A soft-light%3B}"%2C"cartocss_version"%3A"2.1.0"}}\]}&callback=_cdbc_271830228_1`
- API call that does not work:

  `http://rodrigorodriguezmartin.carto**db**.com/api/v1/map?stat_tag=API&config={"version"%3A"1.0.0"%2C"stat_tag"%3A"API"%2C"layers"%3A\[{"type"%3A"cartodb"%2C"options"%3A{"sql"%3A"select * from distritos"%2C"cartocss"%3A"%23layer { polygon-fill%3A %23374C70%3B polygon-opacity%3A 0.9%3B polygon-gamma%3A 0.5%3B line-color%3A %23FFF%3B line-width%3A 1%3B line-opacity%3A 0.5%3B line-comp-op%3A soft-light%3B}"%2C"cartocss_version"%3A"2.1.0"}}\]}&callback=_cdbc_271830228_1`

My CARTO.js application code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/themes/css/cartodb.css" />

<style type="text/css" >
    html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

    body > div.cartodb-header {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #18a68d;
        opacity:0.9;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
        line-height: normal;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--MAPA-->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/cartodb.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Una vez cargada la página, lanzamos la secuencia JS de Carto
        window.onload = main;

        function GetLayerURL(sIdLayer) {
            return "http://" + sUserName + ".carto.com/u/" + sUserName + "/api/v2/viz/" + sIdLayer + "/viz.json";
        }

        var sUserName = "rodrigorodriguezmartin";
        var sURLMapaTodo = GetLayerURL("f884e2a2-29d1-11e7-8322-0ecd1babdde5");

        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        function main() {

            //Generamos el mapa indicando un zoom y unas coordenadas centrales
            var map = new L.Map('map', {
                shareable: true,
                title: 'Titulo',
                description: 'El cambio que se ve',
                search: true,
                loaderControl: true,
                cartodb_logo: false,
                layer_selector: true,
                legends: true,
                fullscreen: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                center: [40.4193612, -3.7018384],
                zoom: 12
            });

            //Añadimos el mapa base
            L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Stamen',
            }).addTo(map);

            //THIS WORK!!! :)
            //cartodb.createLayer(map, sURLMapaTodo).addTo(map)

            //THIS DON´T WORK :(
            cartodb.createLayer(map, {
                user_name: sUserName,
                type: 'carto',
                sublayers: [{
                    sql: "select * from distritos",
                    cartocss: "#layer {  polygon-fill: #374C70;    polygon-opacity: 0.9;    polygon-gamma: 0.5;    line-color: #FFF;    line-width: 1;    line-opacity: 0.5;    line-comp-op: soft-light;}",
                }]
            }).addTo(map)
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of CARTO.js is not compatible with BUILDER `vizjson`s at this moment, as commented [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations). But you still can create CARTO.js apps using `createLayer` method and datasets (or queries) from your CARTO account. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/a0d1fbb0a757b5a45856cfed23962997) you have a working example.

**UPDATE:**

The `vizjson` of your code was generated from [a BUILDER map](https://rodrigorodriguezmartin.carto.com/builder/f884e2a2-29d1-11e7-8322-0ecd1babdde5/embed?state=%7B%22map%22%3A%7B%22ne%22%3A%5B40.356486503120124%2C-3.808822631835938%5D%2C%22sw%22%3A%5B40.49918094806632%2C-3.523178100585938%5D%2C%22center%22%3A%5B40.42787156923612%2C-3.666000366210938%5D%2C%22zoom%22%3A12%7D%7D), and as I mentioned above: **BUILDER `vizjson`s do not work with the current CARTO.js version**. I have replicated your code, now it works (I added CARTO.js v3.15 library instead of v3.14, removed the `vizjson` parts and left only the key parts):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>El cambio que se ve</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
        <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script> 

        <style type="text/css" >
            html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function main() {

                var map = new L.Map('map', {
                    center: [40.4193612, -3.7018384],
                    zoom: 12
                });

                L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: 'Stamen',
                }).addTo(map);

                cartodb.createLayer(map, {
                    user_name: 'rodrigorodriguezmartin',
                    type: 'cartodb',
                    sublayers: [{
                        sql: "select * from distritos",
                        cartocss: "#layer {  polygon-fill: #374C70;    polygon-opacity: 0.9;    polygon-gamma: 0.5;    line-color: #FFF;    line-width: 1;    line-opacity: 0.5;    line-comp-op: soft-light;}",
                    }]
                }).addTo(map)
            }

            window.onload = main;

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not work...I have paste my code in the ask. Are you from Madrid? xD

Comment: Now it works. No, I am not. :-)